# How do I apply CSS to email addresses obfuscated by the Wordpress antispambot function?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using the WordPress antispambot code, from their Code Reference:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/antispambot/

It's working, but I want to style the email addresses that the code displays. If the obfuscated email address is in the footer I want to apply a particular style, but if the obfuscated email address is, for example, in the body of a page I want to apply a different style.

I've tried adding a title attribute to the  tag as shown in the code below:

```
function wpcodex_hide_email_shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {
    if ( ! is_email( $content ) ) {
        return;
    }

    return '<a href="mailto:' . antispambot( $content ) . '" title="encrypted-email">' . antispambot( 
    $content ) . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'email', 'wpcodex_hide_email_shortcode' );
```

And then style it using the following CSS:

```
/* GENERAL STYLE FOR ENCRYPTED EMAILS */

a[title="encrypted-email"]{
    color:#4472e6 !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}

a[title="encrypted-email"]:hover{
    text-decoration:underline !important;
}

/* STYLE FOR ENCRYPTED EMAILS IN FOOTER */

.fusion-footer-widget-area .custom-html-widget a[title="encrypted-email"]{
    color:#ff0000;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}

.fusion-footer-widget-area .custom-html-widget a[title="encrypted-email"]:hover{
    color:#e4d06f;
}
```

However, using the CSS above, ALL encrypted emails, including encrypted emails in footer, take the 'General' styles.

I wondering if this method is the best way to set up different CSS styles for encrypted emails in different parts of the page (eg body text vs footer).

And also, is my CSS correct?

**UPDATE**

The generated HTML is as follows:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <li style="font-size:16px; margin-bottom:0px;"><a 
        href="mailto:&#119;&#98;u&#64;&#98;&#100;" 
        title="encrypted-email">&#119;&#98;&#117;&#64;&#98;&#100;</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the HTML that is generated by the shortcode? We can't help you style the HTML if we can't see exactly what it looks like :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Generated HTML added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. The problem you are having is because of the use of `!important` in your CSS rules.** Using this on your `a[title="encrypted-email"]` rules mean they will take precedence over the more specific "footer" rules.

To make your footer rules take precedence, the most preferable option is to remove `!important` from the main `a[title="encrypted-email"]` - Using `!important` is generally discouraged because it causes problems just like this.

**If that is not possible**, you need to use `!important` on all more specific rules to override the `!important` style. (Assuming the rules match your actual HTML elements), the following should work:

```
/* STYLE FOR ENCRYPTED EMAILS IN FOOTER */

.fusion-footer-widget-area .custom-html-widget a[title="encrypted-email"]{
    color:#ff0000 !important;
}

.fusion-footer-widget-area .custom-html-widget a[title="encrypted-email"]:hover{
    color:#e4d06f !important;
}
```

- **Note** - you don't actually need the `!important` for the text decoration because you are not changing it from the style rule that it is overriding.

**2. You also asked if this is how you should set up the CSS rules for this.** Yes, this is the right way to style them - this is what the *cascading* part of the CSS name means. All you need to override the style is to use a more specific selector e.g. instead of "encrypted email links", you can say "encrypted email links in the footer widget".

So `.fusion-footer-widget-area .custom-html-widget a[title="encrypted-email"]` would normally work for your footer emails (i.e. if the other rules didn't use `!important)` because it is more specific (as long as the email addresses in an element with the class `.custom-html-widget` which is in an element with the class `.fusion-footer-widget-area`of course!)

Comment: Apologies for delayed reply. Thank you for your detailed answer - much appreciated. I have used your suggestions and issue is resolved!